# Get the path of python console commands installed as 'entry_points' with distribute

Tags: python, virtualenv, distribute, entry-point

I'm installing a console command using the [entry_point dict](http://packages.python.org/distribute/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation) in setup.py. This creates a python file in some path in the system (for example, as root in debian is `/usr/local/bin`) that can change depending the system or if you use virtualenvs.

I need the default path of scripts installed as entry_points with setup.py

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you're asking? I don't see a well-formed question here.

Comment: Can you maybe also accept some of your other answers? Bye

Comment: In setup.py you can describe a console_command as an entry_point (http://packages.python.org/distribute/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation) this commands are created in some path in the system, I want to know if there is a way to check that path without assuming is `/usr/local/bin/` because if you install the package inside a virtualenv it will be in another path.

Comment: how do you like to use it? For example, there is `install_dir` attribute in the `setuptools.command.install_scripts` class (you can get it in setup.py if you subclass it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location can vary depending on various arguments to `setup.py`, including `--home`, `--user`, `--prefix`, `--install-scripts` and so on.

If the script already exists, the best way to find it would be to scan over the contents in `$PATH`, looking for an executable file (like the `which` command), but this might not be what you're after

The [distutils.sysconfig](http://docs.python.org/distutils/apiref.html#module-distutils.sysconfig) module might be more helpful.

```
$ export WORKON_HOME='/tmp/so'
$ mkvirtualenv blah
$ python
Python 2.7.2
>>> import os
>>> import distutils.sysconfig
>>> pre = distutils.sysconfig.get_config_var("prefix")
>>> bindir = os.path.join(pre, "bin")
>>> print bindir
/tmp/so/blah/bin
```

..which is the directory where, for example `pyflakes` ends up if I run `pip install pyflakes`

The `get_config_vars` dict might be useful if you need to find a more specific location:

```
>>> [(k, v) for (k, v) in distutils.sysconfig.get_config_vars().items() if "/tmp/so" in str(v)]
[('prefix', '/private/tmp/so/blah'), ('exec_prefix', '/private/tmp/so/blah')]
```

You can more conveniently access some of these variables via the `sys` module, including `sys.prefix` and `sys.execprefix`

Comment: Thank you, this solves my problem, and thanks for the edit in the question :D

Comment: I just noted in the docs that `sys.prefix` will helps as without use `distutils.sysconfig.get_config_var("prefix")`

Comment: @JorgeEduardoCardona No problem! I've edited answer to mention `sys.prefix` etc also, good point

Comment: But what about windows? Is there any cross platform method?